# How to implement one hot encoding without any ML frames in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, categories, image-preprocessing

doing MNIST tutorial without any MLframe, but got stuck in one hot encoding stage

y contains label data of digits images

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

and its size is (10000, )

I want to convert each category numbers to one hot encoding array

0 : 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 : 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 : 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
and so on

so I made a code

```
import numpy as np
y_one=np.zeros(y.size, 10)
y_one[np.arange(y.size), y]=1
```

it says 'data type not understood'

How to implement one hot encoding without sklearn or tf in this case?

Comment: could you add the rest of the error? it will help people trying to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass tuple of ints for `shape` parameter of `np.zeros` function

```py
y_one = np.zeros((y.size, 10))
```